# Error encountered while writing a ERC827 contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

There is an **interface Token20** for writing `ERC20` smart contracts.

> Then there is GauravToken to create an **ERC20** contract from interface Token20.

> Then there is `ERC827` that is for writing an ERC827 contract. I read that ERC827 is an extension of ERC20 . Therefore ERC827 inherits GauravToken ( that is an ERC20 contract ).

But I am getting the following error:

[image][image]

I am new to solidity so also I have doubts about:

> require() takes 2 arguments (but in lines 81 and 88) it's only taking 1.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong here or what is the reason for that ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you upload the screenshot again with this message box removed? Want to see the code.

Comment: @shubhamskatel done sir

Comment: Can you please tell me what do you want to do with the statement `require(spender.call(data)`?

Comment: Please, share the code and error messages as text. It is much easier to test any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low-level call `address.call(data)` returns a list `(bool, bytes)`, but `require` only wants the bool as first argument.

So you need to rewrite all `require` with `call` like this:

```
// 1st function
(bool success, ) = spender.call(data);
require(success);
```

```
// 2nd function
(bool success, ) = receiver.call(data);
require(success);
```

```
// 3rd function
(bool success, ) = _to.call(data);
require(success);
```

The other `require`s all take a `bool` as input (`approve` and `transfer` return bool), that's why they work.

Comment: Is "(bool success , ) = spender.call(data)" like destructuring ?

Comment: @GauravPant yes